# Pass / Pipe / Loop All processes from Get-Process to Powershell PoshInternals script

Tags: windows, powershell, loops, process

How would I pass all processes with Get-Process matching a certain process name  to another PowerShell script one by one ?

pseudocode

```
for each process in matchingprocesses:
  myScript(process)
```

Planned usage Set-WorkingSetToMin script: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshInternals/1.0/Content/Set-WorkingSetToMin.ps1

This works great as there is only one notepad++ process:

```
get-process notepad++ | Set-WorkingSetToMin
```

However for VS Code this only only gets the first code process and ignores the rest:

```
get-process code | Set-WorkingSetToMin
```

How do I pipe each process matching a certain name to powershell script ?

Alternative would be to modify PoshInternals script to accept multiple processes:

```
# Dont run Set-WorkingSet on sqlservr.exe, store.exe and similar processes
# Todo: Check process name and filter
# Example - get-process notepad | Set-WorkingSetToMin 
Function Set-WorkingSetToMin {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.Diagnostics.Process] $Process
    )

if ($Process -ne $Null)
{
    $handle = $Process.Handle
    $from = ($process.WorkingSet/1MB) 
    $to = [PoshInternals.Kernel32]::SetProcessWorkingSetSize($handle,-1,-1) | Out-Null
    Write-Output "Trimming Working Set Values from: $from"

} #End of If
} # End of Function
```

ANSWER in one line without extra variables:

```
foreach ($process in Get-Process myprocessname) { Set-WorkingSetToMin ($process) }
```

Comment: `get-process code | %{Set-WorkingSetToMin}` ?

Comment: I get the following when I run it: Supply values for the following parameters:
Process:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a where clause to pull out just the processes you want, then pipe that set to Set-WorkingSetToMin. An example is below, but adjust as needed to pull exactly what you're looking for.

```
get-process | where {$_.ProcessName -like "*code*"} | Set-WorkingSetToMin
```

Update:
I see what you're saying, the issue is not with the set of processes being sent, but how they're handled once they're there. To get around that, you could set a variable equal to the process set, then loop through them, calling the cmdlet each time. Something like this:

```
$processes = get-process | where {$_.ProcessName -like "code"} | Set-WorkingSetToMin

foreach ($process in $processes)
{
    Set-WorkingSetToMin ($process)
}
```

ANSWER thanks to help from Landon: `foreach ($process in Get-Process myprocessname) { Set-WorkingSetToMin ($process) }`

Comment: How is this different from simply entering Get-Process myprocessname ? Same thing is happening only the first process is processed

Comment: I see what you're saying, the issue is not with the set of processes being sent, but how they're handled once they're there. To get around that, you could set a variable equal to the process set, then loop through them, calling the cmdlet each time. Something like this:

$processes = get-process | where {$_.ProcessName -like "code"} | Set-WorkingSetToMin

foreach ($process in $processes)
{
    Set-WorkingSetToMin ($process)
}

Comment: Thanks! This worked without setting extra variables: foreach ($process in Get-Process chrome) { Set-WorkingSetToMin ($process) }

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Still one annoying thing: The one liner works great from Powershell shell but does not work when run as script.

Comment: Ahh, turns out that is a permissions issue, script only works when run as Administrator